# DBD::CSV and placeholders

Tags: sql, perl, csv, placeholder, dbi

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use DBI;

my $dbh = DBI->connect( "DBI:CSV:", '', '', { RaiseError => 1 } ) or die DBI->errstr;

my $table = 'my_test_table_1.csv';
$dbh->do( "CREATE TEMP TABLE $table( id INTEGER, name CHAR(64) )" );

my $sth = $dbh->prepare( "INSERT INTO $table ( id, name ) VALUES( ?, ? )" );
$sth->execute( 1, 'Ruth' );
$sth->execute( 2, 'John' );
$sth->execute( 3, 'Nena' );
$sth->execute( 4, 'Mark' );

$sth = $dbh->prepare( "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE id > ? LIMIT ?" );
$sth->execute( 1, 2 );
$sth->dump_results;

# Bad limit clause! at /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.20.1/SQL/Statement.pm line 88.
```

It looks like a placeholder in the `LIMIT` clause doesn't work.

How can I tell if placeholders are supported in a certain place in a SQL statement when I use the [DBD::CSV](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::CSV) driver?

Comment: Fixed the `connect` line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Placeholders can only be used where an expression is expected. What follows `LIMIT` must be a row count (not an expression), so it can't be a placeholder.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use DBI qw( );

my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:CSV:", undef, undef, {
   PrintError => 0, RaiseError => 1,
} );

{
   my $sth = $dbh->prepare( "SELECT 1 LIMIT 1" );
   $sth->execute();
   $sth->finish();
   print "ok\n";
}

{
   my $sth = $dbh->prepare( "SELECT 1 LIMIT 0+1" );
   $sth->execute();
   $sth->finish();
   print "ok\n";
}
```

```
ok
DBD::CSV::db prepare failed: Bad limit clause! at .../SQL/Statement.pm line 88.
 [for Statement "SELECT 1 LIMIT 0+1"] at a.pl line 18.
```

Comment: I had no problem using LIMIT with placeholders when using DBD::SQLite, DBD::mysql and DBD::Pg.

Comment: That definitely hasn't always been the case. I think DBD::mysql (rather than the database server) is currently inlining the placeholders (which means the prepare operation is actually done during `execute`). If so, the server never sees the placeholders, just `LIMIT 1`, so it doesn't know you made a syntax error. (e.g. `SET @FOO = 1; SELECT 1 LIMIT @FOO;` fails.) DBD::CSV simply doesn't do all that magic for you.

Answer (score 1):

According to [documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#Placeholders-and-Bind-Values), placeholders can be use only for values.

Comment: Didn't know that the row count is not a value.

Comment: @sid_com: It is a value, but not a column value.